# is it possible to use api-platform resources inside symfony backend without a curl?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

i use api-platform with symfony 5.4. Actually this works fine. I have complex entities with filters that works well on API-plaform. But for a special case, i would like to retrieve data with filters ( like a call on the api endpoint ) in symfony backend. Is it possible ? Or i have to recreate a method with the same filters in a repository ? I don't want to make curl form back end or something like that, i'm just asking if is it possible to access to the api resources from the inside of symfony.

i tried to find some answers on the docs and internet and didn't found anything on it... While the job is done by api-plateform i think this is possible to use it without external request but didn't found a way to do it.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that the short answer is “no, you must interact with your API using HTTP semantics“. That said, API platform actually built a custom [HttpClient](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/main/src/Symfony/Bundle/Test/Client.php) that uses a KernelBrowser which bypasses the network stack which should be possible to use in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, but you could try something different: you can reproduce basic filters with simple repository methods, which are available anywhere in Symfony.
If you defined custom logic inside providers and you would like to reuse it from anywhere, then you could simply centralize this logic inside a repository or a dedicated service and call it from your providers AND from anywhere else in Symfony.